# How to determine wether the data has been completelty send by other end

Tags: node.js, tcpserver, node-streams

As we know that data event is a readable stream and and when it reaches its highWaterMarkValue the corresponding callback will run and I will recive a chunk of the data and process will repeat again(if any data is left)

```
 const tcpServer = net.createServer();
 tcpServer.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log("Connected");
    let data = "";
    socket.on("data", (chunk) => {
        data += chunk.toString("utf-8");
        
         socket.end("Received");
    });
    socket.on("end", () => {
        console.log("Client Disconnected");
    });
});
```

But I dont know when its going to stop sending the data and also dont want to miss out on any data and only end the connection when I will receive the intended amount of data
so is there any way to determine any event or something ?